# How to generate culture specific date pattern from c#

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-asp.net-mvc, date-formatting, kendo-datepicker

My goal is to synchronize the date displaying, generated both by c# and JavaScript.

For c# displaying I am using "d" `.ToString("{0:d}")` pattern.

For javascript I am using kendo datetime picker. This widget accepts the dateTime format in which the value will be shown:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("dateFrom")
    .Format("dd.MM.yyyy"))
```

What I want is to generate culture specific string pattern from c# that I will pass to `.Format()` method.

I know that I can do this manually by using `resx` files. But is there a way for doing this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CultureInfo` class offers all types of date- and numeric formats. So you could use

```cs
var ci = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture; 
var format = ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I need.))